# VirtualBox throws out error while starting the Genymotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I face an error to start the GenyMotion. Its related to the VBox, which fails to start throwing out the following error.

```
Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).


    Result Code: 
    E_FAIL (0x80004005)
    Component: 
    ConsoleWrap
    Interface: 
    IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed

}
```

I have tried almost all of the suggested steps, but no luck. Below is the log of the VBOX. Please go through it and suggest the changes to be made.

```
00:00:03.083017 SUP: windbg> .reload /f C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxDD2R0.r0=0xfffff8800ce28000
00:00:03.083169 APIC: Activating Local APIC
00:00:03.083189 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled APIC
00:00:03.084143 PIT: mode=3 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:03.099389 Shared Folders service loaded
00:00:03.109809 DrvBlock: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:03.109862 DrvBlock: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:03.110233 VD: VDInit finished
00:00:03.197420 VD: Opening the disk took 87513025 ns
00:00:03.197873 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#0: disk, PCHS=4222/16/63, total number of sectors 4256638
00:00:03.197979 DrvBlock: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:03.198012 DrvBlock: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:03.244786 VD: Opening the disk took 46713013 ns
00:00:03.245114 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#1: disk, PCHS=11461/16/63, total number of sectors 11552768
00:00:03.245524 DrvBlock: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:03.245600 DrvBlock: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:03.246926 VD: Opening the disk took 1260752 ns
00:00:03.247185 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#2: disk, PCHS=16383/16/63, total number of sectors 16777216
00:00:03.247252 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#3: no unit
00:00:03.247335 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: finished processing RESET
00:00:03.247592 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:03.248072 IntNet#0: szNetwork={HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter} enmTrunkType=3 szTrunk={\DEVICE\{7195878C-6B25-45F1-8F8E-92C0667BC307}} fFlags=0x8000 cbRecv=325632 cbSend=196608 fIgnoreConnectFailure=false
00:00:03.248243 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-5.0\src\VBox\Devices\Network\DrvIntNet.cpp(1753) int __cdecl drvR3IntNetConstruct(struct PDMDRVINS *,struct CFGMNODE *,unsigned int); rc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND
00:00:03.248297 VMSetError: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter'
00:00:03.248431 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-5.0\src\VBox\Devices\Network\DevVirtioNet.cpp(2082) int __cdecl vnetConstruct(struct PDMDEVINS *,int,struct CFGMNODE *); rc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND
00:00:03.248440 VMSetError: Failed to attach the network LUN
00:00:03.248492 PDM: Failed to construct 'virtio-net'/0! VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND (-3600) - The networking interface to filter was not found.
00:00:03.341920 TxTimer stats (avg/min/max):       0 usec      -1 usec       0 usec
00:00:03.522203 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
00:00:03.522305 Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:03.523335 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:03.614389 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
00:00:03.772330 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 800x600
00:00:03.772404 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={7303a66d-433b-25a4-f9a8-fcadf87e0c2a} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={The console is not powered up}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
```

Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that oracle virtual box doesn't install the network adapter correctly.
Uninstall VirtualBox and Genymotion, install VirtualBox stand alone from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads 
then install the Genymotion package without VirtualBox.

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to delete all previous virtual box adapters and setup properly again

Answer (score 0):

try to uninstall npcap or winpcap if installed, (often comes with network monitoring tools like wireshark) then reinstall genymotion and delete all android devides and create new, this fixed on 2 different windows 10 machines.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for 3 days and all other solutions didnt work for me I found:
[Laravel Vagrant Up SSH Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960545/laravel-vagrant-up-ssh-problems/41402471#41402471)

Where you add

```
 config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]
    end
```

Just before the end tag of your YAML file

And now all works again
Thanks Kratos.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the registry key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Genymobile\Genymotion\host.only.interface"