# Failed to create the host-only adapter

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I have the problem with **vagrant up** on my system. I have the error, you can see below. I have tried reinstall VBox, Vagrant, turned of the firewall, сhecked VBox networking driver and restarted host system, but it`s dont working.

Thanks all for help.

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: SetupDiCallClassInstaller (DIF_INSTALLDEVICE) failed 
(0x00000002)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component 
HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdeclhandleCreate(struct 
HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp﻿
```

**VBox version**
5.2.22

**Vagrant version**
2.2.0

**Host operating system**
Win7 x64

**Guest operating system**
Ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64

**Vagrantfile**

```
dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))

require 'yaml'
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/deep_merge.rb"
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/to_bool.rb"

configValues = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config.yaml")

provider = ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] ? ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] : 'local'
if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{provider}.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{provider}.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
end

if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
end

data = configValues['vagrantfile']

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.8.1'

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  eval File.read("#{dir}/puphpet/vagrant/Vagrantfile-#{data['target']}")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  did `vagrant up` on my host!

After many tries I was reinstall my Windows. The need Virtual Machine host driver (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter in Windows Networking) was installing only on "clean" system that very curiously for me.

Vagrant also need Windows PowerShell version older then 3, but Win7 default using 2. You need update Windows Net Framework for install 3 and older version on Win7.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check this link:

[Failed to open/create the internal network Vagrant on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725779/failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-vagrant-on-windows10)

If that doesn't work then the comment 20 on this And this suggests on https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14545#comment:20

Doing the following:

```
I was able to work around this problem for me with the following steps:
Open the VirtualBox Manager GUI.
Go to File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks
Delete all entries in that list
Run vagrant up again
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but nothing from it dont help me. But seem I understand in what problem. I haven`t VirtualBox Host only adapter in Network Connections Windows. VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking driver is have only in properties of "Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device" http://joxi.ru/Dr8Bj8gC46OVP2.jpg

Comment: Also I cant create this host adapter in "Host-only Networks" (VirtualBox GUI) error SetupDiCallClassInstaller (DIF_INSTALLDEVICE) failed (0x00000002).

Answer (score 0):

I was driving nuts last 2 days with this problem. Finally found a solution.

1.The Antivirus was causing the issue

2.You need to disable to Antivirus services on your windows system (You will need Admin access or get this done from your company IT Person)

3.Reinstall Docker tool box and start it (Admin mode)
This works

Answer (score 0):

I found all other solutions did not work,
till I found this post:
[Laravel Vagrant Up SSH Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960545/laravel-vagrant-up-ssh-problems/41402471#41402471)

where adding the next code just before the end tag in YAML file did the trick

```
 config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread is 3 years old but forward in time and I also had a similar issue with windows 10. Let me show you how I fixed it.

Open virtual box -> file -> host network manager
[image: host network manager]

Once you select the option a box will open with the adapters for you to enable/disable.

By default for me the adapter 2 was disabled, once I enabled it I could run vagrant up with no issues.

[image: adapters]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with `vagrant version v2.3.2` and VirtualBox version `7.0.2` on `macOS Ventura`. In my case, the issue was solved by doing the following:

```
# 1
sudo su
csrutil clear

#2
Then uninstall VirtualBox using the official uninstaller after that reboot the system.

#3
After the reboot install VirtualBox again using:

brew install --cask virtualbox

#4 
Add this line to your Vagrantfile:
virtualbox__intnet: true

#5
vagrant up
```

Also please allow any extensions if prompted by going to System Preferences - Privacy - General and accept the extensions.